# How to compare the values in two different rows with awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Given this file:

```
Variable_name   Value
Aborted_clients 0
Aborted_connects    4
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  141
Bytes_sent  177
Com_admin_commands  0
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_analyze 0
Com_begin   0
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  0
Com_change_db   0
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  0
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    0
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  0
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   0
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  0
Com_insert_select   0
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  1
Com_set_option  0
Com_signal  0
Com_show_authors    0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 0
Com_show_contributors   0
Com_show_create_db  0
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   0
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  0
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 0
Com_show_function_status    0
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   0
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_status   0
Com_show_processlist    0
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 1
Com_show_storage_engines    0
Com_show_table_status   0
Com_show_tables 0
Com_show_triggers   0
Com_show_variables  0
Com_show_warnings   0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute    0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    0
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   0
Com_update  0
Com_update_multi    0
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression OFF
Connections 375
Created_tmp_disk_tables 0
Created_tmp_files   6
Created_tmp_tables  0
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  0
Handler_delete  0
Handler_discover    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  0
Handler_read_key    0
Handler_read_last   0
Handler_read_next   0
Handler_read_prev   0
Handler_read_rnd    0
Handler_read_rnd_next   0
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  0
Handler_write   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   584
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   9568256
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    120
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   7607
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  8191
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    14912
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    584
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   203
Innodb_data_fsyncs  163
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    11751424
Innodb_data_reads   594
Innodb_data_writes  243
Innodb_data_written 3988480
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  120
Innodb_dblwr_writes 40
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   28
Innodb_log_writes   41
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    83
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   34816
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    1
Innodb_pages_read   583
Innodb_pages_written    120
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    0
Innodb_row_lock_waits   0
Innodb_rows_deleted 0
Innodb_rows_inserted    0
Innodb_rows_read    40
Innodb_rows_updated 39
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   13396
Key_blocks_used 0
Key_read_requests   0
Key_reads   0
Key_write_requests  0
Key_writes  0
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Max_used_connections    3
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  86
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  109
Open_tables 109
Opened_files    439
Opened_table_definitions    0
Opened_tables   0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  1
Qcache_free_memory  16758160
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  1
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   419
Qcache_queries_in_cache 1
Qcache_total_blocks 4
Queries 1146
Questions   2
Rpl_status  AUTH_MASTER
Select_full_join    0
Select_full_range_join  0
Select_range    0
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 0
Slave_heartbeat_period  0.000
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats   0
Slave_retried_transactions  0
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    0
Sort_merge_passes   0
Sort_range  0
Sort_rows   0
Sort_scan   0
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher
Ssl_cipher_list
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version
Table_locks_immediate   123
Table_locks_waited  0
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  1
Threads_connected   2
Threads_created 3
Threads_running 1
Uptime  2389
Uptime_since_flush_status   2389
```

How would one use **awk** to make this calculation of Queries per second (Queries/Uptime):

`1146/2389`

And print the result?

I'm grepping 2 results from a list of results and need to calculate items/second where 302 is the total item count and 503 the total uptimecount.

At this moment I'm doing

```
grep -Ew "Queries|Uptime" | awk '{print $2}'
```

to print out:

```
302
503
```

But here i got stuck.

Comment: is your file just like this? if this is coming from a previous `grep`, you can also show what is happening there: most probably `awk` can handle all of it.

Comment: This is the outcome of grep yes. I'll add the complete thing gimme a sec

Comment: May i ask why the downvote?

Comment: No idea why it was downvoted, probably a while ago when it was a bit broad question.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but I could see it being downvoted for the length of the example. Can't you get it down to, say, 10 lines instead of 100 or whatever that is? You should be trying to make it as simple as possible for us to read and there's absolutely no reason why you couldn't make this a much smaller example for us and then scale it yourself later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
$ awk '/Queries/ {q=$2} /Uptime/ {print q/$2}' file
0.600398
```

That is: when the line contains the string "Queries", store its value. When it contains "Uptime", print the result of dividing its value by the one stored in queries.

This assumes the string "Queries" appearing before the string "Uptime".

---

Given your updated input, I see that we need to check if the first field is *exactly* "Uptime" or "Queries" so that it does not match other lines with this content:

```
$ awk '$1 == "Queries" {q=$2} $1=="Uptime" {print q/$2}' file
0.479699
```

Comment: Awesome exactly what i'm looking for. I didn't know how to use variables within awk. Thanks! But somehow it prints 2 times the same value?

Comment: @Baklap4 This can happen because you have multiple lines with "Uptime" in it. Mind to update your question with a more representative sample input?

Comment: I've added the complete file :)

Comment: OK then it is a matter of checking the exact string: `awk '$1 == "Queries" {q=$2} $1=="Uptime" {print q/$2}' file`

Answer (score 1):

I think the following awk one-liner will help you:

```
kent$  cat f
Queries 302
Uptime 503

LsyHP 13:42:57 /tmp/test
kent$  awk '{a[NR]=$NF}END{printf "%.2f\n",a[NR-1]/a[NR]}' f
0.60
```

If you want to do together with "grep" function:

```
kent$  awk '/Queries/{a=$NF}/Uptime/{b=$NF}END{printf "%.2f\n",a/b}' f  
0.60
```

Comment: When will your profile picture show the kid with the SO t-shirt you got? ;-)